# Let $S$ be a normal p-subgroup of a finite group $G$. Prove that $S \subseteq P$ for every Sylow p-subgroup $P$ of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $S$ be a normal p-subgroup of a finite group $G$. Prove that $S \subseteq P$ for every Sylow p-subgroup $P$ of $G$.

Now, I know that this involves the Sylow Theorems, of course. This is very new to me but my thinking so far is this.

S is a normal p-subgroup of a finite group G, so we can say that S has some order of a power of p, $|S|=p^k$ where p is prime and S is a subgroup of some Sylow p-subgroup $K$ (by the second Sylow Th). If I let $P$ be any other Sylow p-subroup, we must show $S \subseteq P.$

Using the third Sylow Theorem, we can state that $K$ and $P$ are conjugates. Thus, there exists $x \in G$ s.t. $xKx^{-1}=P$ Thus, $xSx^{-1} \subseteq P$. But, since S is normal in G, we have $xSx^{-1}=S$.

Please let me know if this is sound theory and if not, please offer corrections.

Comment: It looks just fine to me.

Comment: Very nice. I love proofs like these that don't use 15 functions and a cat.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, exactly that's the way here to use the Sylow theorems.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the intersection of all Sylow $p$-subgroups, $O_p(G):=\bigcap_{P \in Syl_p(G)} P$, is the *largest* normal $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 0):

As $S$ is a normal $p-$subgroup, so, $SP$ is a $\;p-$subgroup. If $S\not\subseteq P$, then $|SP| = p^a > |P| = p^b$, which contradicts maximality of cardinality of Sylow $p-$subgroup $P$. Consequently, $S\subseteq P$.