# Let $H$ be a normal p-subgroup of a group $G$. Proof $H$ is contained in $S$ for all $S$ Sylow p-subgroup of G.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

> Let $H$ be a normal $p$-subgroup of a group $G$. Proof $H$ is contained in $S$ for all $S$ Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.

I'm having trouble trying to understand what is that I have to proof. I don't fully understand the problem so this is what I've got so far.

On my notes I have that: Every p-subgroup is contained in a $S_{p}$-subgroup.

An $S_{p}$-subgroup is the same as a Sylow $p$-subgroup?

Also there's a Lemma that states: If $S$ is a $S_{p}$-subgroup of $G$ and $H$ is a p-subgroup then $H\subset N_{G}(S)$ if and only if $H\subset S$.

I'm pretty lost so any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you are using "$S_p$" to denote a Sylow $p$-subgroup, yes. Do you know Sylow's Second Theorem?

Comment: I don’t have the Sylow theorem numbered but I think is that if $P$ is a Sylow p-subgroup then its conjugates are Sylow p-subgroups.

Comment: It's more than that: it's also that if $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup, then all Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugates of $P$. So if $H$ is a normal $p$-subgroup, you know it's contained in *some* Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$. You want to show it is contained in *all* Sylow $p$-subgroups, so let $Q$ be any Sylow $p$-subgroup. What is the relation between $P$ and $Q$?

Comment: If $P$ is a Sylow p-subgroup then for any $Q$ Sylow p-subgroup and for any $g\in G$ $P=gQg^{-1}$ and because $H=gHg^{-1}$ and it's contained in $P$ it implies that $gHg^{-1}\subset gQg^{-1}$. Is that correct?

Comment: Careful: it is not true that "for all $g\in G$, $P=gQg^{-1}$". What is true is that **there exists** $g\in G$ such that $P=gQg^{-1}$. The rest is messed up, too. $H\subseteq P$, you want to show $H\subseteq Q$. Your conclusion at the end, though, is $H=gHg^{-1}\subseteq gQg^{-1}=P$, so you are concluding what you started with!

Comment: I think I rushed my answer a little bit. $P=gQg^{-1}$. Because $H\subset P$ then $H\subset gQg^{-1}$ this implies that $g^{-1}Hg\subset Q$ but because $H$ is normal we have $H\subset Q$

Answer (score 1):

If $S \in Syl_p(G)$ and $H$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$  normalizing $S$, which is $H \subseteq N_G(S)$, then $HS$ is a subgroup. In addition, $|HS|=\frac{|H| \cdot |S|}{|H \cap S|}$, which is a $p$-power. Since $S$ is a maximal $p$-subgroup, and $S \subseteq HS$ it follows that $S=HS$, or equivalently, $H \subseteq S$. The converse is trivial.

Different proof: observe $S \unlhd N_G(S)$, so, applying Sylow theory *inside* $N_G(S)$, this latter group has a unique Sylow $p$-subgroup, namely $S$. If the $p$-subgroup $H \subseteq N_G(S)$, then by your first note ("every $p$-subgroup is contained in *some* Sylow $p$-subgroup"), again you get $H \subseteq S$, since there is no other!

Comment: This gives the quoted lemma. Does the lemma help with the problem in the title?

Comment: See different proof added.

Comment: I still don't see how this proves that if $H$ is normal in $G$, then $H\subseteq P$ for all $P\in Syl_p(G)$. How do we go from "$H\triangleleft G$" to $H\subseteq N_G(S)$?

Comment: You are right, this is a different matter of course. @TheMadMax IV Sylow subgroups are conjugate to each other, so if $H$ is normal and contained in *some* Sylow $p$-subgroup, then $H$ is contained in *all*, since conjugation leaves $H$ untouched so to speak.

Comment: Check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200216/let-s-be-a-normal-p-subgroup-of-a-finite-group-g-prove-that-s-subseteq-p?rq=1